# Removing .php makes problems with .inc

Tags: php

I just removed the .php extension from my website by using the code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But now my login.inc.php makes an error?
How to fix please.

Comment: What error? If it's not showing on screen, check the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i just need to make another .htaccess file under the directory of the .inc.php file with the same code and now it works!